# Diagonalizable Matrix over the complex field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

The question is:

> Is every complex matrix such that $A^2=A$ diagonalizable?

My reasoning goes as follows: If $A^2=A$ then left multiplying the inverse of $A$ on both sides yields $A=I$. I'm pretty sure this shouldn't be that easy.

Comment: If $A^2=A$ and $A$ is invertible, then it *is* that easy. However, $A$ may not be invertible. But here is a hint: What are the possible eigenvalues of $A$? Also, what happens if you square $I-A$?

Comment: This can't be right. $A$ equal to the zero matrix also satisfies $A^2 = A$. What's a necessary or sufficient condition for $A$ to be diagonalizable? Do you know about Jordan normal form yet?

Comment: Why would you use Jordan normal form for such elementary question? That's really a thing on S.E, to overuse theorems all the time. As @Kevin pointed it out, a split simple root polynomial P that verify P(A) = 0 is more than enough to assure that A is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

$P=X^2-X=X(X-1)$ is a split simple root polynom which cancel $A$, so $A$ is diagonalizable.